# Proof that β-function ∈ C^∞

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, smooth-functions

I need to find correct proof that β-function is smooth on its domain.

Is there some feature of such functions,  I guess that we need to prove the continuity of all n-derivatives,  or their partial derivatives,  but how it will be eventually I hadn't got yet.  I will very glad your help.

Comment: You need to write in latex, click on edit in the other post to see how. That the $\beta$ function is $k$-times differentiable in each of its variable is not hard. To see it is analytic you can expand $t^{x-1}$ as a series in powers of $x+c$.

Comment: Which function do you mean:
[Dirichlet's $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) or
[Euler's $B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)?

Comment: Euler's Β function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than enough to differentiate through the integral sign (the Leibniz rule.) For example, thinking of $x,y>0,$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt = \int_0^1(\ln t)t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt.$$

You can keep going, piling up factors like $(\ln t)^m \ln (1-t)^n$ in the integral. None of these factors will destroy integrability.